# Two color scales for different geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm getting some strange behaviour when trying to create difference geom_rect in different facets. In the below example, the colour of the geom_point should be the same as the fill of the geom_rect, which should be the same as the outline of the geom_rect. However, the factors seem to be becoming concatenated in a weird way somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

I don't want the points to be coloured by sequence, as the cluster and sequence will not always be identical (it is for visualising a permutation statistic).

THESE ARE OBVIOUSLY NOT THE ACTUAL DATA THAT I WANT TO PLOT!

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

scatter.dt = data.table(sequence = factor(paste('Sequence',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        cluster = factor(paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        outcome = c(1,1,1,1),
                        transition.time = 1:4,
                        intervention.time = 1:4)
vline.dt = data.table(sequence = scatter.dt$sequence,
                      cluster = scatter.dt$cluster,
                      transition.time = 1:4,
                      intervention.time = 2:5)

plot1 = ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_rect(data = vline.dt,
                     aes(fill = sequence,
                         colour = sequence,
                         xmin = transition.time, 
                         xmax = intervention.time, 
                         ymin = -Inf, 
                         ymax = Inf),
                     alpha = .6,
                     size = 2) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(data=scatter.dt,
                      aes(x=transition.time ,
                          y=intervention.time,
                          colour = cluster),
                      alpha=1,
                      size = 4) +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(sequence + cluster ~ .)

plot(plot1)
```

Should also have cluster colours in the same order as sequence colours when data are generated thus:

```
scatter.dt = data.table(sequence = factor(paste('Sequence',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        cluster = sample(factor(paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4)), levels = paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4)))),
                        outcome = c(1,1,1,1),
                        transition.time = 1:4,
                        intervention.time = 1:4)
vline.dt = data.table(sequence = scatter.dt$sequence,
                      cluster = scatter.dt$cluster,
                      transition.time = 1:4,
                      intervention.time = 2:5)
```

[image]

Comment: in the `geom_point` call, the colour parameter should be set to sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was pretty clear that this was a toy example, the simplest version of my problem, as these data themselves are pretty pointless!

Comment: As in my previous edit _I don't want the points to be coloured by sequence, as the cluster and sequence will not always be identical (it is for visualising a permutation statistic)._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `ggnewscale`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

scatter.dt = data.table(sequence = factor(paste('Sequence',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        cluster = factor(paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        outcome = c(1,1,1,1),
                        transition.time = 1:4,
                        intervention.time = 1:4)
vline.dt = data.table(sequence = scatter.dt$sequence,
                      cluster = scatter.dt$cluster,
                      transition.time = 1:4,
                      intervention.time = 2:5)

plot1 = ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_rect(data = vline.dt,
                     aes(fill = sequence,
                         colour = sequence,
                         xmin = transition.time, 
                         xmax = intervention.time, 
                         ymin = -Inf, 
                         ymax = Inf),
                     alpha = .6,
                     size = 2) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  ggplot2::geom_point(data=scatter.dt,
                      aes(x=transition.time ,
                          y=intervention.time,
                          colour = cluster),
                      alpha=1,
                      size = 4) +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(sequence + cluster ~ .)

plot(plot1)
```

[image]

With data generated:

```
scatter.dt = data.table(sequence = factor(paste('Sequence',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        cluster = sample(factor(paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4)), levels = paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4)))),
                        outcome = c(1,1,1,1),
                        transition.time = 1:4,
                        intervention.time = 1:4)
vline.dt = data.table(sequence = scatter.dt$sequence,
                      cluster = scatter.dt$cluster,
                      transition.time = 1:4,
                      intervention.time = 2:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the colour parameter in the `geom_point` call to sequence. That way you get

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

scatter.dt = data.table(sequence = factor(paste('Sequence',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        cluster = factor(paste('Cluster',c(1,2,3,4))),
                        outcome = c(1,1,1,1),
                        transition.time = 1:4,
                        intervention.time = 1:4)
vline.dt = data.table(sequence = scatter.dt$sequence,
                      cluster = scatter.dt$cluster,
                      transition.time = 1:4,
                      intervention.time = 2:5)

plot1 = ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_rect(data = vline.dt,
                     aes(fill = sequence,
                         colour = sequence,
                         xmin = transition.time, 
                         xmax = intervention.time, 
                         ymin = -Inf, 
                         ymax = Inf),
                     alpha = .6,
                     size = 2) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(data=scatter.dt,
                      aes(x=transition.time ,
                          y=intervention.time,
                          colour = sequence),
                      alpha=1,
                      size = 4) +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(sequence + cluster ~ .)

plot(plot1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the points to be coloured by sequence, as the cluster and sequence will not always be identical (it is for visualising a permutation statistic).

Comment: Good answer for this question - the OP did not make their point very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing several color scales. Creating more than one scale for one aesthetic is not easily possible without some hacking. Or extra package. One option is to use `ggnewscale`. However, I personally think, plots with as few scales/ dimensions/ colors as possible are best for effective visualisation.

The easiest solution is simply remove the color from your rect - thus you'll leave the color scale to your points only without losing any information and making the plot more efficient (less convoluted).

(Please note I've removed the unnecessary data.table load and the `ggplot::` which you don't necessarily need when loading ggplot2 completely.

Important to actually set your scale to different values, otherwise ggplot will use exactly the same values for your fill and color scales. Note I have used brewer scales, they are usually color blind friendly. You can find and look for suitable palettes at 
[colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3)

Like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

scatter.dt <- data.frame(sequence = factor(paste("Sequence", c(1, 2, 3, 4))), cluster = factor(paste("Cluster", c(1, 2, 3, 4))), outcome = c(1, 1, 1, 1), transition.time = 1:4, intervention.time = 1:4)
vline.dt <- data.frame(sequence = scatter.dt$sequence, cluster = scatter.dt$cluster, transition.time = 1:4, intervention.time = 2:5)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = vline.dt,
            aes(fill = sequence,
                xmin = transition.time, 
                xmax = intervention.time, 
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf),
            alpha = .6) +
  geom_point(data=scatter.dt,
             aes(x=transition.time ,
                 y=intervention.time,
                 colour = cluster),
             size = 4) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Dark2')+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Blues') +
  facet_grid(sequence + cluster ~ .)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>