# Problem with multiple variable in color aesthetic in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to do a graph with 2 different set of data, like this example:

```
library(ggplot2)

t <- data.frame(x=c(3,5, 7), y=c(25, 25, 27), text=c("t1", "t1", "t2"))
test <- data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=c(20:29), factor=c(rep("a", 5),rep("b", 5)))

  ggplot(test, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=factor)) +
  geom_text(inherit.aes=F, data=t, aes(x, y, label=text, color=text))
```

The resulting figure is:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the legend is mixing the data from both data.frame in the same legend. And I don't manage to quit the values from the geom_text. Anyone has an idea please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two color scales for different geoms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133345/two-color-scales-for-different-geoms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two scales for the same aesthetic is generally something that you may want to avoid. Try not to overload your graph with too many dimensions to visualise with the same aesthetic. Especially colors have only a limited range where we can differentiate them.

Well, these were my two-cents worth. What you want has become easy with `ggnewscale`.

See below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

textframe <- data.frame(x = c(3, 5, 7), y = c(25, 25, 27), text = c("t1", "t1", "t2"))
lineframe <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(20:29), factor = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = lineframe, aes(x, y, color = factor)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_text(data = textframe, aes(x, y, label = text, color = text)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

[image]

Better would be a different aesthetic. Here for example very appropriate would be `linetype`.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = lineframe, aes(x, y, linetype = factor)) +
  geom_text(data = textframe, aes(x, y, label = text, color = text)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Paired')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the text part of the legend by adding `show.legend = FALSE` in your `geom_text`. You also don't necessarily need to specify `inherit.aes=F`.

```
t <- data.frame(x=c(3,5, 7), y=c(25, 25, 27), text=c("t1", "t1", "t2"))
test <- data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=c(20:29), factor=c(rep("a", 5),rep("b", 5)))

test %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=factor)) +
  geom_text(inherit.aes=F, data=t, aes(x, y, label=text, color=text), show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Biomiha ! I tried and unfortunately It gives the same result  ...